# How to escape special alphabets in php

Tags: php, regex

How to escape special alphabets like " Ã " in string using php.
I have tried below code for it:

```
echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through `preg_replace`, it would be done using the below regex.

```
((?![A-Za-z])\p{L})
```

Then replace the matched accented characters with `\\\1` .

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kG5vF1/5)